# Transform an empirical distribution to be more "exponential"

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, transformation

I have a distribution of about 70k results (empirical) that looks like the following (normed to percentage):
[image]

I want to transform the distribution to be exponential, 
I tried to scale the distribution to be in  (0,1) and use  inverse transform sampling

```
def inverse(X, lambd):
"""Inverse  of exponential distribution """
return -np.log(1-X)/lambd
```

But didn't get a good result. How can I construct a transformation function to make my distribution exponential ?

Comment: Estimate the exponential parameter from your data, that's all.

Comment: After Ill get my Lambda, how can I transform my results to have "exponential" distribution similar to the  exponential distribution with the lambda estimated?

Comment: If you want expo distrib you've got it with that lambda.

Comment: I'm trying to find a function that will map my data points  to an exponential distribution